# ArcGIS: accessing python list output from listFields geoprocessor

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm trying to access the output from the `listFields` geoprocessing object using the following code:

```
sFields = gp.ListFields(linktofeatureclass)
for j in range(len(sFields)):
    print sFields[j]
```

How do I get information about the fields that I have enumerated? Printing them (i.e. `sFields` in the above) just returns "geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x00E42E18". I'm looking for the field name, type, length, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sFields = gp.ListFields(linktofeatureclass)
for field in sFields:
    print field.Name, field.Type, field.Scale
```

For more information, consult with [the docs](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Field_properties).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and the pointer to the docs - much appreciated.